# I designed a game that makes my eyes tired

Tags: color, critique, games, composition, accessibility

I try making a game where you draw physic lines and need to deliver a ball to the exit. I created several levels and found that I cant play it. My eyes get tired and hurt after 10 minutes.

Maybe the problem is bad colors combinations or  bad background or in something else? Or maybe the problem is in my eyes? I am not designer and need your help and suggestions.

Attached images of 2 levels.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whoa those title caps. But joking aside, I think that a lot of times what hurts people's eyes is the animation or movement within the game. Maybe it's too "flashy". I wouldn't be able to say for sure based on stills.

Comment: Do you have that problem with other games as well?

Comment: as @AshleePalka suggests, this may be a low framerate issue. If your game or elements in it is around 5-30hz (fps), this can cause seizures in some people. In some people this may present as eye fatigues and drowsiness. This is why games tend to have seizure warning screens. http://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bt/R-REC-BT.1702-0-200502-I!!PDF-E.pdf

Comment: So yeah, Pikachu once sent hundreds of children to the hospital: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denn%C5%8D_Senshi_Porygon

Comment: Not enough contrast between BG and FG?

Comment: You should take a look at our [critique requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/682/2611) and make sure your question matches all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see too much detail, and this combined with some movement (That depends on what pieces of your game moves) could make some flickering. Take a look at that.

Find a methodology. Make a test without the background woods, one with less detail on the grass, or less spikes together (i.e. instead of 12 jut put 4).

Confirm your frame rate too.

Also some people just can not stand some types of games. I played a looooot 3D games since Wolfenstein 3D... Now I cannot play some of them. I get sick.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your elements are too realistic and detailed which is overloading your brains image processing. Try using simpler elements (leaves for example).

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed or downvoted.

Comment: I think in this instance he hits the mark pretty well - a citation to brain image processing would be nice tho  @Luciano